# Select multiple elements in a regular expression

Tags: regex, capture

I've got the URLs in the following style:

```
http://whatever.com/param1/val1/param2/val2
```

I want to match all `key/value` pairs. I tried this pattern:

```
/^http:\/\/whatever.com(?:\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+))*$/g
```

It only matches the last key/value pair.

Unfortunately, I cannot use code to get the pairs... How can I capture all pairs?

Comment: Why not just `split` on the forward slash?

Comment: @RoccoC5 you mean by coding ? because it should be processed only with a regex

Comment: What programming language is this? And why "should it only be processed with a regex"? In this case a non-regex solution would most likely be much simpler.

Comment: @RoToRa :  
* "What programming language is this?" : Just generic Regex  
* "And why "should it only be processed with a regex"?" : Because it is supposed to work with a client interface only working with regex  
* "In this case a non-regex solution would most likely be much simpler" : yes, for sure, it would be simpler

Comment: @jney: There is no such thing as "generic regex", each implementation  has it's differences, and the environment is important, because what you want is most likely not possible with a simple one-time application of a regex.

Comment: I see nothing recursive in this description.  Why the tag?

Comment: @RoToRa : i'm not if php or java is used as server side language

Answer (score 0):

Try making your match *non-greedy* by adding a `?` after the `*`:

```
/^http:\/\/whatever\.com\/(?:([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?)*?$/g
```

Comment: i still match only the last couple of results

Comment: Please please please write that with a different delimiter, and `/x`, so you can read it: `m{ ^ http: // whatever \. com / (?: ( [^/] + ) / ( [^/]+ ) /? ) *? $ } xg`. The LTS ( “leaning toothpick syndrome” ) is really really bad here: I see a giant DOUBLEYOU in front of *whatever*: `\/\/`, which I doubt works as an appreciation for *www*. :) It probably should have newlines and indentation, too. Please make regexes one can read. BTW, that pattern won’t actually pull out all key-value pairs just because you used `/g` or quantified them, you know.